# Set space between axis label and axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way of specifying the position of axis labels?

`labelpad` sets the space between tick labels and the axis label.
Since the width of tick labels is unknown it appears to thus be impossible to precisely position axis labels.

Here is a MWE where I would like to have the ylabels of both subplots to be vertically aligned:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(19680801)
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

for ax in axs:
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability $y$')
    ax.grid(True)

ax.set_yticklabels([ r'\$\num{{{:g}}}\$'.format(item) for item in ax.get_yticks().tolist() ])

fig.show()
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
ylabelposition = ax.yaxis.label.get_position()
ax.set_yticklabels([ r'\$\num{{{:g}}}\$'.format(item) for item in ax.get_yticks().tolist() ])
ax.yaxis.label.set_position(ylabelposition)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: In your example it appears the y-label moves to accommodate the tick-labels being longer than their unformatted counterparts - perhaps including the output you see would better illustrate what exactly the issue is. Would you be able to post the outputs?

Comment: @Ghost I added the visual output